# how do I change default import setting on phpMyAdmin, currency to decimal(5,2)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, lamp

When phpMyAdmin uploads an .ods file with currency, it converts it to a decimal.  The data type it uses is decimal(5,2).  I need to change the precision and the range on the default import configuration.  How can I do that?

I'm running LAMP, phpMyAdmin, on Amazon AWS.

Comment: What if you create the table structure then import the data (rather than letting phpMyAdmin pick the structure)? One way to do that might be to import the file, truncate the table (which clears the data, leaving the structure), then modifying the data type before importing again.

Comment: I don't know how to vote for the correct answer, but that's the fix.  I'm a noobie, wanted a user-friendly GUI, but in the end, command line won.